# java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen cannot be cast to android.preference.GenericInflater$Parent

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferences

The app crashes immediately on launch and I cannot really work out why. Ive read online, that this error can occur when I dont use the androidx libaries everywhere. I havent found an old one so here I am. I dont know what exactly is the problem. I first had this problem after my pc froze while I was working on the app. Before it compiled just fine and everything worked as intended, after the crash I had to reset the emulator and delete a couple of R.java files, which belonged to a custom libary for app intros of Github.

**Logcat**

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.computertycoon/com.example.computertycoon.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen cannot be cast to android.preference.GenericInflater$Parent
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen cannot be cast to android.preference.GenericInflater$Parent
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:328)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:271)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:343)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:670)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:629)
    at com.example.computertycoon.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:244)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
```

**SettingsActivity**

```
package com.example.computertycoon;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // View-Elemente aus XML-Layout Datei erzeugen lassen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    // Initialisieren der App Bar und Aktivieren des Up-Buttons
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_settings_activity);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.action_settings));


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**SettingsFragment**

```
package com.example.computertycoon;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;


public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements
    Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    Preference currency_list = findPreference("currency_list");
    currency_list.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    Preference switch_box_show_idle_dialog = findPreference("switch_show_idle_dialog");
    switch_box_show_idle_dialog.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

    if (preference.getKey().equals("switch_show_idle_dialog")) {
        boolean switch_show_idle_dialog_Value = (boolean) newValue;

        Log.i("abc", "toggled switch_show_idle_dialog, new value: " + switch_show_idle_dialog_Value);

        return true;
    } else if (preference.getKey().equals("currency_list")) {
        String currency_list_Value = (String) newValue;

        Log.i("abc", "changed currency, new currency: " + currency_list_Value);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;

    }
}
}
```

**Preferences.xml**

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_general">

    <ListPreference
        android:id="@+id/currency_list"
        android:entries="@array/currency"
        android:entryValues="@array/currency_values"
        android:key="currency_list"
        android:title="@string/settings_currency"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/settings_appearance">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="switch_show_idle_dialog"
        android:summary="Get notified about your earnings which you got while being idle"
        android:title="Show welcome dialog"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        app:defaultValue="true" />


</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_other">

    <Preference
        android:key="button_reset"
        android:summary="@string/settings_repeat_intro_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_repeat_intro">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            android:targetClass="com.example.computertycoon.IntroActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.computertycoon" />
    </Preference>



    <Preference
        android:key="button_reset"
        android:summary="@string/settings_this_cant_be_undone"
        android:title="@string/settings_reset_game"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_red_48dp">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            android:targetClass="com.example.computertycoon.ResetActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.computertycoon" />
    </Preference>

</PreferenceCategory>


</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: The crash occurs during creation of MainActivity, so it would be helpful if you showed its code and layout.

Comment: I just fixed the problem. Thanks for your comment. The "x" in import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager; was missing inside of the MainActivity.